# I get "No implementation found error" when using libpag in android

Tags: java, android

I want to use libpag on android, but I get a No implementation found error.
https://github.com/Tencent/libpag

I created a project in androidstudio and then configured it as described in the github README.
https://github.com/Tencent/libpag#android-integration

Operating environment abi is x86.

I tried using the sample repository and no error occurred, so I am wondering if the gradle configuration is bad.
https://github.com/libpag/pag-android.git

```
2022-03-22 12:59:03.906 3824-3824/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 3824
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.libpag.PAGPlayer.nativeInit() (tried Java_org_libpag_PAGPlayer_nativeInit and Java_org_libpag_PAGPlayer_nativeInit__)
    at org.libpag.PAGPlayer.nativeInit(Native Method)
    at org.libpag.PAGPlayer.<clinit>(PAGPlayer.java:222)
    at org.libpag.PAGView.setupSurfaceTexture(PAGView.java:310)
    at org.libpag.PAGView.<init>(PAGView.java:226)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7989)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3316)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3485)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2045)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
    ndkVersion "21.4.7075529"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.tencent.tav:libpag:3.2.7.37'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.libpag.PAGView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final PAGView pagView = new PAGView(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you still have this problem? Maybe you should try to specify the abiFilters property in gradle, by setting it to armeabi only. libpag does not have the x86 arch support, but you always can use armeabi arch instead for x86 devices.